# Why does my program stop when tabbed into a different window?

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard

I'm new to programming and thought I could make a simple "strafe bot" to help me aim train in first person shooters. The idea is that it randomly inputs keys "a" and "d" for random amounts of time to simulate left to right movement. It works great while I'm tabbed into the console app but when I tab into any other application it stops. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

The whole script (I used the Input Simulator NuGet Package):

```
using System;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using WindowsInput;
using System.Threading;

namespace StrafeTrainer1
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool endthesuffering = true;

            ConsoleKeyInfo effSix = Console.ReadKey();
            if (effSix.Key == ConsoleKey.F6)
            {
                endthesuffering = false;
            }
            
            InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
            
            Random randomD = new Random();
            Random randomT = new Random();

            while (endthesuffering == false)
            {

            int randomDirection = randomD.Next(0, 2); //Determines Strafe Direction
            int randomTime = randomT.Next(0, 800); //Determines Strafe Time
                
                if (randomDirection == 1)
                {
                    sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
                    Thread.Sleep(randomTime);
                    sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
                }
                else if (randomDirection == 0)
                {
                    sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
                    Thread.Sleep(randomTime);
                    sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.VK_D);
                }

                ConsoleKeyInfo effSeven = Console.ReadKey();
                if (effSeven.Key == ConsoleKey.F7)
                {
                    endthesuffering = true;
                }
                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but there is another problem with you random numbers. If you create 2 `Random` objects in a row, they will very often generate both the same random number sequence. This is because the use the current time to initialize the sequence. But the PC clock is slow compared to the CPU clock. So, they both might "see" the same time. Create only one `Random` object and use it for both direction and time.

Comment: It may be better to ask at https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator Also https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator/issues/33 suggests that this libary doesn't work in the background.